# General variations of a functional with a second order derivative?

Tags: calculus-of-variations

I have seen how to derive the general variation of a functional of first order. However, when I try to apply the methods to higher order functional, things break down. How does one derive the boundary conditions/ equations of motion for the general variation (I.e. endpoints also vary) of these higher order functionals?

Answer (score 0):

The functional $f(x,y,y',y'')$ can be represented as

$$
f(x,y,y',y'')\equiv f(x,y,z,z')+\lambda(x)(z-y') = F(x,y,z,z')
$$

now applying the stationary conditions

$$
F_y-\left(F_{y'}\right)' = f_y-\lambda' = 0\\
F_z-\left(F_{z'}\right)' = f_{z}+\lambda-\left(f_{z'}\right)'=0
$$

eliminating $\lambda$ we obtain

$$
f_y -\left(f_{y'}\right)'+\left(f_{y''}\right)''=0
$$

which are the Euler-Lagrange stationary conditions for the functional $f(x,y,y',y'')$

Comment: I'm referring to the case where the boundary points are allowed to vary as well; e.g. in the case of a functional depending only on the first derivative, you end up with a boundary term composed of the F_y'i's times the variational in y and the hammiltonian term of the system times the variational in x

Comment: @RichardWilde I will try to enlarge the variation to those situations. Just now I only considered fixed end points. Thanks.